# Drag and drop an object from oustide browser in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have a question about drag and drop with protractor. Can i drag something from desktop or other path to browser in Protractor test?
In browser i have this code and it works:

```
describe('TEST', function() {

it('Info', function() {
browser.get('http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/');

  var dragElement = element(by.model('list1'));
  var dropElement = element(by.model('list2'));

browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(dragElement)
    .mouseDown()
    .mouseMove(dropElement)
    .mouseUp()
    .perform();
    browser.pause(30000);

});
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/drag-files-into-the-browser-from-the-desktop-HTML5.html#fbid=60s_eIxMGu4)?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. The protractor opens a browser in different context.
It can contact with elements on the **DOM** - Items from the desktop, etc. are not recognized by the protractor.
You **can** read\write files and so on by using javascript, but can't run actions on them.